# position:fixed not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

I am having some trouble with a 'fixed' element in Google Chrome.  The element behaves as it should in other major browsers.

Here is the CSS:

```css
#element { 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The issue is, when the page loads, the element is fixed at the bottom of the viewport, as it should be.  Upon scrolling, it remains at the same spot where it was when the page loaded - it doesn't stay fixed to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: There must be more to your problem as it can't be reproduced with that CSS rule on chrome, ie. http://jsbin.com/UcIpANol/1/ works just fine on Chrome.

Comment: Can you maybe add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding the following code to your element:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: glad I could help. I almost ate my eyes designing multi-device/browser stuff... edit: also if it helped, accept is as the correct answer, it might help others as well

Comment: that makes it even worse for me: Compare http://jsfiddle.net/Supuhstar/t04nh943/ to http://jsfiddle.net/Supuhstar/t04nh943/2/

Comment: also try removing relative elements. It might be tough to replace but there's always a way

Comment: This works so well - for me the element I was giving position fixed  did in fact move, but it became invisible for some reason when scrolling and if you were to click on it's position it would sometimes become visible on that spot and the spot it's previously loaded in on, so it also works for such an issue - Thank you!

Comment: Looking to your answer, made me look at my `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` and remove it from parent element. While was with it, just made my child element static and not fixed. - Thank You.

Comment: How and why does it work? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20503545/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 9):

I had a property: `-webkit-perspective:800;` on the body tag. I removed this and the fixed positioning started working again... obscure, but worth a look.

Comment: It also works for me if I removed the perspective property but I need it for a parallax effect... This sucks.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the won answer: **this would not work** if you have **"-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d"** in one of the parent elements. I don't know why, I just had such and removed it.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour happens when one of the parents of the `position:fixed` element has one of the following properties modified:

- `filter`
- `transform`
- `backdrop-filter`
- `perspective`
- `contain`
- `transform-style`
- `content-visibility`
- `will-change`

According to [the specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty), this generates a containing block for absolute and fixed positioned descendants.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937920/4045812) you can find more informations about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable:

```
-webkit-transform: none !important;
transform: none !important;
```

to make it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put a left position too for this to appear...not just a top:

```
{
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me.
What worked for was setting the **contain** property of the parent element to **none**:

```css
{
  contain:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `position: sticky; bottom: 0;` for now.

```
#element { 
   position: sticky; <--- 
   bottom: 0px; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 50px; 
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete what the other answers are saying, also be aware that setting the `will-change` property on any parent element will break fixed positioning.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First check if any parent have

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(...);
```

or

```
transform: translateZ(...);
```

or

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(...)
```

or

```
transform: translate3d(...)
```

and try removing them.

---

If still doesn't work try adding

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

or

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

to your element.

---

If still doesn't work check for other -webkit-transform / transform / perspective styles on parents and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing

```
filter: blur(0);
```

in the parent element.
I only had this issue with chrome, it was working well with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

The property `will-change:transform;` was causing the issue for me.
I just needed to add `will-change:auto;` to override it.

Answer (score 0):

For me none of these solutions helped,
the problem turned out to be one of my Chrome extensions.
Disabled all extensions and the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
contain: none;
```

in the parent element.