# Polymer: How can I add a footer below a core-list?

Tags: css, polymer, core-elements

I want to put a footer below a `core-list` so that when you scroll to the end of the list the footer appears below it (i.e. the footer is not always visible).

How do I do that?

A related problem, is how to put variable spacing at the sides of a `core-list`, such that the spacing elements have the same height as the list.

Note, that I also want the `core-list` to be inside a `core-animated-pages` which is in turn inside a `core-scroll-header-panel`

## Edit

My failed attempts are in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yuwazo). Note the jsbin is a modified clone of the one I used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132532/polymer-core-transitions-for-animated-pages-with-core-list-content) as it's all part of a related set of problems for me

Comment: Where's the (re)search? Where's the problem? Next thing we'll know will be people coming here asking "I want a website".

Comment: My failed attempts are in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yuwazo). Note the jsbin is a modified clone of the one I used in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132532/polymer-core-transitions-for-animated-pages-with-core-list-content) as it's all part of a related set of problems for me