# Why position:fixed not working on Chrome?

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I have a header on my website that contains a button that I want it to be sticky at the top while scrolling.

You can view the website here:https://logosperformance.com/

When I give the element containing data-css="tve-u-163a8211f58":

```
position:fixed;
```

Or any element of its containers , It doesn't work on Chrome but works on Mozilla.

Is it not supported on Chrome or there is CSS property from Chrome `-webkit-` that blocks it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position:fixed not working in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503424/positionfixed-not-working-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;`:

```
.thrv-page-section:not(.tve_evt_manager_listen):not(.tve_symbol_inside),
.thrv-content-box:not(.tve_evt_manager_listen):not(.tve_symbol_inside) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
  -moz-transform: none !important;
}
```

Replace it with:

```
-webkit-transform: none !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the sticky element out of its parent div (tcb-flex-col).

Comment: ! Thanks for the tip. This actually fixed my issue with both Chrome and mobile 